# Firebase Sign Out in Cloud Functions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Can't figure out how I can sign out for an user in Cloud Functions for Firebase.

My case is the following: a user sings up with Facebook, then I check user data in Functions, in case the data incorrect I have to 1) sign out the user 2) delete the user profile. Currently I can delete user with `admin.auth().deleteUser(user_uid)`, but can't sign out and then catch `onAuthStateChanged` callback in my Android app. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You currently can't "catch" a user deletion in a mobile app.  If you need to sign out a user, simply do that immediately in the client.  There's no need to use an auth state listener to trigger antyhing.  There's also no need to wait for the Cloud Function to complete.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, going to try Firebase Remote Config to fix this